# Why Program 1 is working but not Program 2, could anybody explain whats wrong with Program 2?

Tags: c++

Program 1 is working fine but Program 2 is giving a compilation error, could anybody tell whats wrong with Program 2..

Program 1

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char* a[3] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    const char*(*p)[3] = &a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << (*p)[i] << std::endl; // this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**NO COMPILATION ERROR**

Program 2

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    const int* a[3] = { 1, 2, 3};
    const int*(*p)[3] = &a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << (*p)[i] << std::endl; // this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**COMPILATION ERROR**

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const int *
```

Comment: According to the analogy you try to draw, `"one"` is a `char`. But it's not.

Comment: The compiler already tried to tell you whats wrong. Do you have trouble understanding the error message?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's going on. `a` is an *array of `int` **pointers***. But you are assigning just integers to it. You're attempting to assign `int` values to a type `cont int *`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann yes, i was unable to understand the error message

Comment: @lurker In the first Program also I am doing the same right, I am assigning names ('char') to it.

Comment: I understand the confusion. But it's not the same at all. In the first program you're assigning literal strings to `const char  *` which is allowed since C++ references the literal string by it's pointer (address). Thus the literal string is a `char *`. If you think about a simpler type without the array, you can declare a single variable, `const char *s = "Hello";`, or `const int a = 1;`.

Comment: `"one"` is a `char*`, `1` is a `int` not an `int*`

Comment: @lurker I understood the error, thank you very much, if possible please write this in the answer. This is the answer I am expecting

Comment: @Detonar, Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"one"` is a `char*`, `1` is a `int` not an `int*`

Therefore, Program2 would have to be:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    const int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3};
    const int (*p)[3] = &a;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << (*p)[i] << std::endl; // this line
    }
    return 0;
}
```